# Finding RMSE for predicted values

Tags: r

I am trying to find the RMSE model of the predicted values for log(price) and log(lotSize) by using the dataset SaratogoaHouses in the library(mosiacData). lotSize has two values equal to 0, which will produce -infinity when you take the log.  Remove these rows from the data

This is what I have so far but I get an error:

```
install.packages("mosaicData")
library(mosaicData)
data("SaratogaHouses")

model = predict(lm(log(price)~log(livingArea),data = SaratogaHouses))

x <- summary(model)

x$sigma

Error in x$sigma : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `summary` of the model and not the predicted values. Try :

```
model <- lm(log(price)~log(livingArea),data = SaratogaHouses)
predicted_values <- predict(model)
x <- summary(model)
x$sigma
#[1] 0.3298453
```